# Url for routing to specifc version with SSL and custom domain on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

Is there a url pattern that will *by default* route traffic to a specific version using a custom domain and SSL on app engine, without specifying the routing in a disptach file? I.e. something like

`https://themagic.mydomain.com`

Where `themagic` may include dots, dashes - whatever it takes?

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#routing_via_url) specify various options, but none that are both SSL and mydomain.com, they are:

> https://instance-dot-version-dot-module-dot-app-id.appspot.com
>   http://instance.version.module.app-id.my-custom-domain.com
>   Sends the request to the named module, version, and instance.
>
> https://version-dot-module-dot-app-id.appspot.com
>   http://version.module.app-id.my-custom-domain.com
>   Sends the request to an available instance of the named module and version.
>   These address forms have a default routing behavior. Note that the default routing is overridden if there is a matching pattern in the dispatch file:
>
> https://module-dot-app-id.appspot.com
>   http://module.app-id.my-custom-domain.com
>   Sends the request to an available instance of the default version of the named module.
>
> https://version-dot-app-id.appspot.com
>   http://version.app-id.my-custom-domain.com
>   Sends the request to an available instance of the given version of the default module.
>
> https://app-id.appspot.com
>   http://app-id.my-custom-domain.com
>   Sends the request to an available instance of the default version of the default module.

For several years I have been using the routing

`https://version1.www.mydomain.com`

This historically worked fine to route traffic to the version called `version1` on the default modile, and continues to work. But I'm uncomfortable with it because a) it's not documented (as far as I can find) b) it's tricky to get the SSL setup. Specificall on the SSL, the only way (as far as I can tell) is to use a wildcard SSL cert (which is either pricey, or self signed). My attempts to use this URL with an SSL cert signed only for `version1.www.mydomain.com` resulted in the traffic being routed to the default version, presumably because of the specific 'custom domain' rules that one needs to add via appengine's web UI (cloud console) in order to add the SSL cert. So for now, a self signed wild-card cert is the only way I can make it work.

Through experimentation, it also seems that `version-www.mydomain.com` may be a valid routing to that version, but again, whether this can be setup with SSL is in doubt, and there's no docs on it.

If at all possible, please link to documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

It appears that while this is working as intended, it's not a case of soft routing, but rather `subdomain -> version / module` routing described elsewhere on the same docs page linked originally. There was an issue with the form of the subdomains shown in the docs at the time this comment exchange occurred, which should be fixed shortly to be more clearly readable.

```
https://module-dot-app-id.appspot.com
http://module.app-id.my-custom-domain.com
```

Should become:

```
http(s)://module-dot-appid.appspot.com
OR
http(s)://module.appid.appspot.com
OR
http(s)://module.custom-domain.com
```

Or an equivalent.

**Original answer**

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#routing_via_url) you linked adequately describes the routing rules. What you've observed in terms of default-module routing is an example of the "Soft Routing" the docs describe. Explicit addressing of modules and versions will need to take the form the docs requires, else the request will go to the default module.

Comment: thanks for answering. Sorry, my question was unclear (hopefully clarified now). I have https://version1.www.mydomain.com routing traffic to `version1` - i.e. that url is routing as I wish, but it's undocumented, and a pain to setup SSL. The soft routing rules you linked to say: a) "If a request matches the app-id.appspot.." (which this url does not) and b) "Soft routing does not apply to custom domains", which is what we're dealing with here. So I think that unfortunately, the soft routing rules do not clarify this.

Comment: What have you got in the `App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains` section of the Developers Console? Did you opt for `www.` or the naked domain? One option would be to set it up for the naked domain, and have www route to the default module using dispatch rules, while the other subdomains which resolve to versions or modules will route properly, and you'll only need a singly-nested wildcard (`*.mydomain.com`).

Comment: I have 3 entries: 1) mydomain.com, with SSL Support from my LetsEncrypt cert, a bunch of A and AAAA records, no alias. 2) www.mydomain.com, with SSL Support from my LetsEncrypt cert, one cname record and alias 'www'. 3) \*.www.mydomain.com with SSL support from my self-signed cert, one cname record, and alias "\*.www".  I tried setting up version1.www.mydomain.com with and SSL cert for just that domain, and that's what caused the traffic to route to the default version. Either way, the docs seem to say that version1.www.mydomain.com will route to default version, but it routes to version1.

Comment: I believe you should only need to configure one of the three options you have. The subdomains prefixed to the given pattern will be considered when resolving modules. Given that you have `www.mydomain.com` and `*.www.mydomain.com`, prefixing `version1` should naturally resolve to version `version1`. This appears to be working as intended. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: prefixing `version1` to `*.www.mydomain.com` routes traffic to `version1`. So this is the observed behavior and the behavior I want, and (as you say) the 'intended'. But I just can't see where it is documented (which is my main concern). Sorry, I've read those docs 10 times, and I don't see it. Please could you edit your question again to quote the parts which document this behavior? Sorry if this seems pedantic - I assuming that if I'm having trouble with these docs other people might too, so it's worth pushing to completion. If you think that assumption is incorrect then please LMK.

Comment: Is `version1` by any chance the default version?

Comment: I've noticed that each example in the docs shows domains of the form "version.module.appid.customdomain.com", which seems odd. The "appid" shouldn't be there as far as I know. This would be the actual issue you are attempting to highlight, no? This confusion will be clearede up I think, once you noticed that the correct behaviour is to resolve subdomains of "mydomain.com" to versions/modules, not subdomains of "appid.mydomain.com". Have I grasped the nature of your confusion here?

Comment: I've just confirmed that indeed, this represents an issue in the docs' clarity. We'll have the page updated soon to show that "appid" is not a necessary component of the domain. I hope that all is now clear, feel free to reply if not!

Comment: thanks. Correct `version1` is not default. Correct, the presence of `appid` in the examples makes them not fit my pattern. One other thing: all the examples for my-custom-domain.com are http, not https. I'm taking this to literally mean that the version/module routing patterns only work on my-custom-domain.com when not served over https. Is that not the case? Maybe it should say http(s):// ? Thanks for getting the docs straightened out.  There is one final issue about whether an SSL cert can be setup for such a url w/o using a wildcard cert. Want to continue that here, or elsewhere?

Comment: You're correc that it should read http(s), as well. An SSL cert can be set up for these URLs, as long as the cert matches the FQDN. If you use the `-dot-` convention you can manage to fit all the version / module information into a single subdomain, meaning only one wildcard is needed. I'm not sure if there are any other questions remaining.

Comment: Thanks Nick. http(s):// makes much more sense. There is a remaining question on setting up SSL certs, but perhaps I should ask it as a new question. The summary is: I created a cert for `version1.www.mydomain.com`, added it as a 'custom domain' in web console, and then learnt (to horror) that the traffic was being routed to the default version, not `version1`. I fixed that by using a wildcard cert instead. Q is: should it be possible to use this routing pattern on https w/o a wildcard cert? If yes, then I'd should write up the details in full. If not, then no need.

Comment: p.s. would you mind updating you answer here so that i can accept it? thanks!